# onclick event is executed immediately without clicking

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm working on some code that contains a click event for a span element (This piece of code is part of the function that creates the span):

```
$("span[class=addnewsqlwherevalue][id='" + opts.counters[3] + "']").click(
function(e) { ...});
```

It is executed immediately after it is defined there and also when I click the specified span element although I only want it to be executed when I click on the element.

I also tried:

```
function clickSpan(e) {...} 
$("span[class=addnewsqlwherevalue][id='" + opts.counters[3] + "']").onclick = clickSpan;
```

In the above case it is executed never.

```
$("span[class=addnewsqlwherevalue][id='" + opts.counters[3] + "']").on('click', function(e) {...}); // same as the first approach
```

I looked at similar questions but they didn't contain a solution that worked. This code is not from me, so I might miss something but I assume that nowhere in the code this onclick event is executed (because the function is called exactly when it is created).

Please bear with me, I'm new to javascript and I need to find several bugs in a big project.

Comment: did you try using the bind method to bind the click event instead or the click method?

Comment: @developer82 bind is deprecated and should not be used. The `click` and `on` syntax used is fine. You say that code is the part which *creates the span* - there is no creation code here, only binding to the click event. You should show all relevant code for this span

Comment: then maybe try using is first on all span objects, and see if it auto fires.

Comment: `on()` is the right way to define the event and cannot be executed automatically. So I would ask to check if the click event is not invoked in another place in the code using `.click()` or `.trigger('click')`

Comment: If you remove the id part, the code snippet is working perfectly in that case. [here is the fiddle for it](http://jsfiddle.net/cvSgj/1/). It shows opts not defined in console..

Comment: @sdespont Thank you very much, I didn't know about trigger. And I have no clue why it was called there. Now it works!

Comment: @ExpectoPatronum great, I have copy my comment as answer to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer has been found in the question comment. Here is just a copy/paste of the comment to close the question properly.**

`on()` is the right way to define the event and cannot be executed automatically. So I would ask to check if the click event is not invoked in another place in the code using `.click()` or `.trigger('click')`