# How make an onclick event not load at all until it is actually clicked

Tags: javascript, php

I'm an extreme novice when it comes to javascript, I have a simple onclick button that loads text into modal box. The thing about it is that it also invokes a php function. On page load or refresh the php function is automatically triggered without clicking the button! How can I make it so that the button must be clicked before invoking the php function.

**EDIT:**
The proposed duplication answer that was provided explains the logic behind why my question doesn't work but doesn't offer steps to take to fix it nor a path to take to learn how to render my question properly. The answer I posted addressed my issues directly.

Ive gotten some tips from the following pages but i havent been able to put it together properly I suppose:

[onclick event is executed immediately without clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966687/onclick-event-is-executed-immediately-without-clicking)
[onclick event ocurring without click event actually happening - js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53238367/onclick-event-ocurring-without-click-event-actually-happening-js)

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" onclick="buildFunction()">
```

Javascript:

```
 <script>
        function buildFunction() {
            document.getElementById("package").innerHTML = "Initializing Powershell...</br>";
            document.getElementById("package").innerHTML += "Initializing Connection to Build Server...<br>";


            document.getElementById('package').onclick = function() {
                <?php buildPackage() ?>;
            };
        }
</script>
```

PHP Function:

```
function buildPackage()
{
    $serverName = "\\\\Server";
    $msiName = '"""""""""ARG1"""""""""';
    $installDir = '"""""""""ARG2"""""""""';

    $runCMD2 = "start powershell.exe psexec -accepteula -s -i 2 " . 
    $serverName . " cmd /c D:\path\to\app.hta " . $msiName . " " . 
    $installDir;

    $execCMD = shell_exec("$runCMD2");

    echo "Starting Build...<br>";
    echo $execCMD;
    echo "Build Complete";
}
```

Comment: *"How can I make it so that the button must be clicked before invoking the php function."* php is executed on the **server**, **then** the page is rendered on the **client**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: Try `addEventListener("click", () => { <?php buildPackage() ?>;})` instead of `onclick`

Comment: @NabeelMehmood that will change nothing in the order of execution. PHP will still be executed first

Comment: @NabeelMehmood much appreciated but ```document.getElementById("package").addEventListener("click", function(){<?php buildPackage() ?>;})``` still invoked without the event

Comment: You should create a endpoint to call buildPackage function, example: "http://yourdomain.com/buildPackage". In code javascript you call above endpoint to proccess in server when user click button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was found using the answer to this method which relies on using ajax to call the php function from an external file:

[How to call a php script/function on a html button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27716499/how-to-call-a-php-script-function-on-a-html-button-click)